# The Era Of The Ear

Tags: mathematics, alphametic

Given this information,
\begin{matrix}
  & E & R & A \\
+ & E & A & R \\
\hline
  & A & R & E \\
\end{matrix}
What is the sum of $A$, $R$, and $E$ and if you can find specific values, please list them out, too.
**So far, none of you have gotten what I have been asking**

Comment: The main solution offered by the answers fits all the information you've provided, leaving off bothering to sum the three digits. Because there is no hint of any different interpretation, it *is* a solution to your puzzle, even if it is not the one you wanted. A petulant proclamation of "That is Wrong!", without providing any hint that would contradict the solution, changes your puzzle from a moderately interesting "deduce the answer from the clues" into a very uninteresting "make wild guesses as to what I'm thinking".

Comment: "What is the sum of , , and ?" is the question. "If you can find specific values, please list them out, too." is the optional part.

Comment: If someone has listed out the only solution, summing them together is trivial. To say "you didn't solve this" because they didn't actually add the three values together is ... picayune.

Comment: Besides which, daw has provided the sum, and you denied that was a solution as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to compute $A+R+E$ without actually solving the puzzle for precise values of $A,R,E$.

> Which is not so exciting, as there is a unique solution for all digits.

> From the second and third column it is clear that $A+R>10$, so $A+R=E+10$, and $A+R+1=R+10$ (so $A=9$).

> Then the first column implies $2E+1=A$.

> Putting everything together: $A+R+E = 2E+10 = A+9 = 18$.

> Of course, we can solve for $R$ and $E$ as well: the previous sentence already implies $E=4$, so $R=5$ follows.

Answer (score 9):

> A + R = 10 + E
>  A + R + 1 = 10 + R
>  R = E + 1
>  2E + 1 = A
>  A = 9, E = 4, R = 5

Comment: a very mathematical way to solve this, nice

Comment: That first line warrants an explanation, me thinks... (not a terribly complicated one, but why not spell it out?)

Answer (score 5):

> Everyone's already found the (9,4,5) solution, but there's also the trivial one: (0,0,0).

> We know there's no carry from the third column because of the number of digits of both addends matches the number of digits of the sum.

> If we assume there's no carry from the other columns, then we get:
>  A + R = E
>  R + A = R
>  E + E = A

> From the second equation we can get A = 0.
> Then from the third we get 2E = 0. Then E = 0.
> Then substitute on the first equation to get R = 0.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick way of solving for the sum $S=A+E+R$ without solving for the individual digits (I'll leave out the latter since it has been done in many of the other solutions):

> Because $S$ is the digit sum of either term and the sum in the given equation we must have $S+S = S+9C$, i.e. $S = 9C$, where $C$ is the number of carries occurring in the sum. As the pairs of digits summed in the relevant (lowest and middle) places are identical (both $A$ and $R$), $C$ is either $0$ or $2$. But $0$ does not make sense, thus $C=2$ and $S=18$.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at the hundreds place, the number of digits doesn't change. So E must be 4 or less, because E + E = A = an integer of 9 or below.

> We have two options for the ones column. Either A + R is less than 10 or greater, so A + R = E if A + R if less than 10, or if A + R if greater than 10, A + R - 10 = E.

> Looking back to the hundreds place, the equations E + E = A and A + R = E don't jive with integers. So E must be equal to A + R - 10.

> So Far: 
> A = E + E
>  R = ?
> E = A + R -10

> This means that 
> E = 2 E + R - 10
> E - 2 E = R - 10
> -E = R - 10
> E = -R + 10
> E + R = 10

> So now we have:
> A = 2E 
> R = 10 - E
> E = A + R -10

> Looking back to the tens column, we have the 10 carried-over from A + R, so 1 + R + A = R. This means that R - R = 0 = A + 1.... So A = -1...????. This doesn't make sense if the digits are integers from 0 to 9....

Comment: You can look at Sconibulus’s solution. They missed part of what was supposed to be the answer.

Comment: @Tyler: A = E + E is not true, there is a carry from A+R as you have noticed. So A = E + E + 1

Answer (score 0):

I just found the combination for **R + A + 1 = R** and this way I found **A = 9**. From here **R** is already known to be **5** and the rest is history.

```
  459
+ 495 
-----
  954
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another type of solution.

Based on Sconibulus's solution (I can't add a comment to his answer),

> These are the values in base 4: A = 3, R = 2, E =1

And the sum of A R E is

> ER (6 in base 4)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked what the sum would be, I would think about assigning specific numbers to the three letters *A, R & E* as *X, Y & Z*. So the sum goes like this : *X*+*Y*+*Z*

But the sum presented in the question is nothing but adding the same group of terms to itself in a changed order and the answer to it is itself the same set of letters arranged in different order.

So all the three different arrangements of *A, R & E* basically represents

*X*+*Y*+*Z*

In short *X*, *Y* & *Z* should add up in one specific sequence to give the sum in any other sequence which is true for any set of values of *X*, *Y* & *Z*.

As Guillermo Lago mentioned, (0,0,0) is a solution that satisfies the condition despite it being a trivial one. In addition to that, there can be any set of three numbers (*X*, *Y* & *Z*) that will satisfy the given condition of sum.

Comment: I can't see any actual answer to the question here. Are you saying that any three numbers $X,Y,Z$ will do?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Though I doubt my answer.